# Не срабатывает событие keydown при повторном нажатии ALT

Tags: javascript, события, keydown

Событие нажатия клавиши альт срабатывает только один раз, но при клике правой кнопкой мыши в рабочей области снова срабатывает один раз...

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown',witch_key_down);
document.addEventListener('keyup',witch_key_up);

function witch_key_down(e){ 
 if (event.keyCode=='18') window.alt=true;  
 document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=window.alt;
}



function witch_key_up(e){ 
 window.alt=false;    
 document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=window.alt;
}
```

```html
<div id="output">false</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Думаю проблема тут не в самом *Javascript*, а в самом нажатии на <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Потому что когда человек в браузере (как и в большинстве программ) нажимает просто <kbd>Alt</kbd>, то он попадает на меню браузера (и если нажать например стрелку ↓, то оно появится):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

То есть, в итоге, все работает, но в сочетании с <kbd>Alt</kbd>, скорее всего, лучше работать одновременно с другими клавишами.

---

**P.S.** служебные клавиши можно проверять не по номеру `keyCode`, а вот так:

`event.ctrlKey`, `event.altKey`, `event.shiftKey`, `event.metaKey`